# I am not able to call my php code from form submit, why is this?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I can't get the php code to run! Would anybody know what the problem is? I'm not sure of the way I called the pHp code makes sense. Everything works but a file is not saved.

- The code is supposed to display a list of subjects in a bullet
  pointed list as I ask the user to keep putting in subjects until
  submitted.
- The code is then supposed to save this list in a csv file like this
  (Math, Biology, English etc) but I dont think the php code is
  running.

```html
<html>
<h1> Fill in Subjects </h1>
<input type='text' id='input' />
<input type='button' value='add subject' id = "add" />

<input type='text' id='input2' />
<input type='button' value='remove subject' id='remove' />

<div id='list'>
</div>
<p> When Submit button is clicked, you can not come back to this page!</p>
<form method="POST" action=''>
<input type='button' value='Submit' id = "subjectsub" name = "complete" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var subjectli = [];
document.getElementById("subjectsub").onclick = function(){
JSON.stringify(subjectli); 
}
document.getElementById("remove").onclick = function(){
 document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = "";
 var toRemove = document.getElementById("input2").value;
 var index = subjectli.indexOf(toRemove);
 if (index > -1) {
       subjectli.splice(index, 1);
    }
  var sList = "";

  for (var I = 0; I < subjectli.length; I++)
  {
       sList = "<li>" + subjectli[I] + "</li>";
       document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += sList;
  }
  document.getElementById("input2").value = ""; // clear the value 
 
}
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {

  var text = document.getElementById("input").value; 
  subjectli.push(text);
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = text;
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
  document.getElementById("input").value = ""; // clear the value
}

</script>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['complete']))
{
    $subjectA=json_decode($_POST['jsondata']);
 $fp = fopen('file1.csv', 'w');

 foreach ($subjectA as $fields) {
  fputcsv($fp, $fields);
 }

 fclose($fp);
}

?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

The input elements need to be within the form if you want them to be posted with the form submit.

```
<div id='list'>
</div>
<p> When Submit button is clicked, you can not come back to this page!</p>
<form method="POST" action=''>
   <input type='text' id='input' />
   <input type='button' value='add subject' id = "add" />

   <input type='text' id='input2' />
   <input type='button' value='remove subject' id='remove' />
   <input type='button' value='Submit' id = "subjectsub" name = "complete" />
</form>
```

Comment: I tried this but it keeps giving me these errors and I don't know the cause:Undefined index: jsondata in C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJECT\staff interface\subjects.php on line 50

Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJECT\staff interface\subjects.php on line 52

Comment: I've taken a closer look. You'll need to do three things for it to work the way it's currently set up.
1. Use preventDefault to stop the form from submitting. 
2. Use JavaScript to JSON.stringify your input (as you're currently doing) and
3. Make an AJAX request to the subject.php

Answer (score 1):

Form elements should be inside the form tags as the other answerer mentioned. And be sure to put the form processing file inside the form action attribute like this:

`<form method="POST" action='myFileName.php'>`